# Can you use the Apple Watch with an iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-watch

I may or may not be be getting the new Apple Watch. Before I think about it I want to know if I can use it with an iPod Touch 5th generation instead of an iPhone.

Is the apple Watch locked to the iPhone 6 only or can I use it with an iPod Touch. If I can use it with a iPod what features will I loose or what will the ones be available.

Comment: nope, only iPhone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On [every page about the Apple Watch](http://www.apple.com/watch/technology/), it's stated at the bottom of the page that Apple Watch :

> Requires iPhone 5 or later.

This means no iPod touch.

Comment: I saw about that but I didn't know it meant iPhone only or iPhone and iPod. I thought it meant it didn't work for android. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

From Apple's website: "Apple Watch works with iPhone 5 or later running the latest version of iOS, which introduces the Apple Watch app. So make sure everything is up to date"

**Note:** While it does say "Requires iPhone 5 or later." in the footnotes at the very bottom of the http://www.apple.com/watch/technology/ mentioned by Matthieu Riegler, nonetheless it's important to note that both the iPhone 5 and later must have at least iOS 8.2 or later.  So an iPhone 5 still running iOS 7.x will not work with the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot use Apple Watch with an iPod touch. The Apple Watch app is also not available on that device.

Comment: ["The Apple Watch only works with iPhone (duh)"](http://gizmodo.com/apple-watch-everything-you-need-to-know-1632172509). Also, I can tell from my own iPod touch's homescreen, that the Watch app is not present, although iOS 8.2 is installed.

Answer (score -4):

You can still use it. The only thing the phone allows it to do is call, receive texts, check distance you've gone (GPS) or some other key features like camera. Everything else is still accessible to to it being able to connect to wifi.

Comment: But iPods don't have GPS'

Comment: My iPhone does a heck of a lot more than that to my watch.  I actually wish it did less.